# Is there an Ansible command to check all essential logs of a web server environment?

Tags: debugging, ansible

I use Debian stable and Apache 2.4.

In the past I wrote a script with 3 different commands to read all logs of my webserver. Like:

```
#!/bin/bash

nginx -t && echo;echo;echo
tail /var/log/access.log && echo;echo;echo
tail /var/log/error.log
```

Right now for my personal websites I use **Apache** instead.

Is there an Ansible command to check all essential logs of a web server whether Apache/Nginx, or any other webserver with significant usage (statistically) ?

A total "server-environment" command can also be good (say, something that would include Postfix/Ssmtp as and so forth, as well).

Comment: I'm personally not aware of such a role/play, but you could just use those commands with the `command` module. I'd recommend writing the output to a local file on the respective server and then fetch that for viewing (the output of ansible is ... ummmm ... shall we say **unsightly** .... )

Comment: @tink: You should use to `debug` module to make Ansible Playbook output appear. That’s the exact advice Red Hat Support Engineers gave me in the topic. Not a big fan of it... but it works.

Comment: Ansible is a configuration management tool, not a log monitoring tool. The fact that you’re using Ansible doesn’t prevent you from running your own small scripts such as this one (which doesn’t alter the system state).

Comment: Perhaps you should take a look at something like https://goaccess.io. I think it's more appropriate to what you seem to want to do.

Comment: @Mxx goaccess.io sure does seem like a serious log monitoring tool (I would say LMT), but will you say it is an overkill if I only desire small webserver debugging like in the script in the question?

Comment: It'll be a pity to delete this session. I invite users to write an answer synthesizing the good comments that basically say "no, there isnt as for 2019". and I'll accept it.